# Adjust element position on negative left value

Tags: html, css

I have three divs that are adjacent with each other. What I want to do is overlap the first div with the middle div using a negative left property. After doing this, I want the third div to still be adjacent to middle.

Normally, what will happen is that the space that the middle div is suppose to occupy is still there and the third div will position itself after the space, leaving a gap between the middle div and the third div.

To solve this, I also need to put a negative left property on the third div to move it beside the middle div. Is there a property that I can set to any of the three element (or the div container that holds the three divs) to avoid putting the negative left property on the third div?

Comment: Could you show the CSS that you implemented to attempt this?

Comment: ...and picture with what you want to achieve?

Comment: Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/rw2wm/

The problem is in my actual program, the divs have different widths, so I have to compute for the negative value that I have to put to each left property. The only constant thing that I want to do is overlap the preceding element by 10px.

Answer (score 0):

How are the three divs placed adjacent to each other? If all three divs are `float`ed, you can use a negative `margin-left` on the middle div rather than a negative `left`.

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/Z2rB4/7/

Comment: This seems to be fine. Thanks sir.